# How many routing parameters can you have?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

How many routing parameters can you have in .NET MVC?
Like localhost:port/controller/action/parameter1/parameter2/parameter3/ and so on

I'm currently using this for my routing

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{extra}/{extra2}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, extra = UrlParameter.Optional, extra2 = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

And this works great. 
But when I add yet another routing like an "extra3" in this example the whole page just breaks, ordinary form posts and so on stops working.

Is there a limit to how many you can have and should I rather just make normal querystrings?

**Edited**

To explain it further.
I want to do this

```
routes.MapRoute(
     name: "Default",
     url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{extra}/{extra2}/{extra3}",
     defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, extra = UrlParameter.Optional, extra2 = UrlParameter.Optional, extra3 = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

But it just simply does not work when I add even further amount of routes/parameters.
Is there a limit to how many you can have?

Comment: What do you mean by the whole page breaks? Do you get any error messages? Does the page load at all?

Comment: @musefan I'm using url.action for various things and they all stop working, like as if they never get executed anymore. And this only happens when I add an extra routing/parameter.
I've added new routings/parameters over time so this isn't the first time I've done that, but its the first time its causing problems probably due to a limit or similar

Comment: Did you try keeping the default one and add this one with new name?

Comment: @Saranga I mean that I add an extra /extra3 to it, like controller/action/id/extra/extra2/extra3. To the default maproute

Comment: So what do your `url.Action`s look like? Can you manually navigate to a page if you type directly into the URL?

Comment: @musefan it looks like an ordinary one url.Action("Action", "Controller") but when I added extra3 to the optiona routing MapRouting it just stopped working, it doesn't type out the url anymore, just blank.
While my redirectToUrl functions gives 'No route in the route table matches the supplied values.' as an error. 
This only happens when I add the extra 'extra3' parameter route to my MapRoute, if I remove it it works fine.

Comment: Try removing the `UrlParameter.Optional` for all your `extra`s and the `id`.

Comment: @ReCaptcha Removing them all together caused "The Web server is configured to not list the contents of this directory." errors while replacing the UrlParameter.Optional with quotes "" still causes the same issue as before where all the url.Action, redirects and so on stops working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML Helpers e.g. (`Html.ActionLink, Html.Action, Html.BeginForm etc`) gives wrong results when there are more optional parameters in routs. Normally we keep one optional parameter at the end of the route as optional.

If you keep the routing config as follows it will work.

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Default",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{extra}/{extra2}/{extra3}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, extra = UrlParameter.Optional, extra2 = UrlParameter.Optional, extra3 = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

    routes.MapRoute(
         name: "OneOptional",
         url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
         defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

}
```

Read the section "*The Root Cause*" of following post understand the issue with multiple optional parameters.

http://haacked.com/archive/2011/02/20/routing-regression-with-two-consecutive-optional-url-parameters.aspx/

Thanks!